# re.sub (python) substitute part of the matched string

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I have a series of strings which are identifiable by finding a substring "p" tag followed by at least two CAPITAL letters.

Input:

```
<p>JIM <p>SALLY <p>ROBERT <p>Eric
```

I want to change the "p" tag to an "i" tag if it's followed by those two capital letters (so not the last one, 'Eric').

Desired output:

```
<i>JIM <i>SALLY <i>ROBERT <p>Eric
```

I've tried this using regular expressions in Python:

```
import re
Mytext = "<p>JIM <p>SALLY <p>ROBERT <p>Eric"

changeTags = re.sub('<p>[A-Z]{2}', '<i>' + re.search('<p>[A-Z]{2}', Mytext).group()[-2:], Mytext)
print changeTags
```

But the output uses "i" tag + JI in every instance, rather than interating through to use SA and then RO in entries 2 and 3.

```
<i>JIM <i>JILLY <i>JIBERT <p>Eric
```

I believe the problem is that I don't understand the .group() method properly. Can anyone advise what I've done wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way using look-ahead assertion:

```
re.sub(r'<p>(?=[A-Z]{2,})','<i>',MyText)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your inner `re.search` is only evaluted once, and the result is passed as one of the parameters to `re.sub`. This can't possible capture all the capital-letters-pairs, only the first one.  This means your approach cannot work, not merely your understanding of `groups`.

Furthermore, using `groups` is unnecessary.

---

You need to capture the capital letters using parenthesis, and reference it as `\1` in the substitution expression:

```
re.sub('<p>([A-Z]{2})', r'<i>\1', Mytext)
```

`\1` here means: replace with the substring matched by the first `(...)` in the regular expression. ([docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub))

Note the leading `r` in front of the substitution string, to make it *raw*.